# What's the difference between "overrun" and "infest"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

> Our kitchen is overrun with cockroaches
>   The barn was infested with rats

What's the difference between *overrun* and *infest* in those examples? And if they mean the same, which one is more common in everyday English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Overrun" and "infested" are essentially synonyms in this case, meaning that they are interchangeable in your example. You can say both

> Our kitchen is overrun by cockroaches.

and

> Our kitchen is infested with cockroaches.

Remember, however, that overrun is usually followed by "by" and not "with" when used passively. I would say though that in this case, "infested" would be more commonplace here because that word gives a connotation that there's a large group of wild animals/insects that can harm people or spread disease. The word "overrun" is usually more neutral or used in a war setting. For example,

> The battlefield has been overrun by enemy troops.
>
> Germany lost World War II because they were overrun by America soldiers at all fronts.
>
> After the 2010 midterm election, Congress soon became overrun by Republican politicians.

I've also seen the word "overrun" used for objects and more harmless animals,

> The Atlantic Ocean, in the last ten years, has been overrun by catfish, disrupting the ecological balance of the sea.
>
> Legos are going to overrun the toy shelves this holiday season.

In consensus, "infested" usually has a negative connotation whereas "overrun" is more flexible as it can be applied to many more situations. If "overrun" is giving you trouble, think of a synonym such as "inundate", "occupy", "invade", or "overwhelm".

Comment: To whoever downvoted me, please comment on what's wrong with my answer

Comment: Thank you so much that's really helped me but i wanted to ask is the word " teeming with " has the same meaning

Comment: "teeming with" is like both overrun and infested except it's a more general, all-around version. You can say the forest is teeming with bugs or the town is teeming with tourists. That word is more multi-purpose, can be neutral, negative, or positive.